# Trying to use position: absolute for Facebook Like in IE7

Tags: html, css

I have this site: [www.canalonesbastimar.com](http://www.canalonesbatimar.com) Im trying to place the facebook button below the phone numbers in IE7, but I can't .. Im using a relative position for the container and an absolute position for the facebook button..

```
<div class="tel-fb">
    <div class="telicon my-icons-telicon" style="float: left"></div>
    <div id="tel" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HomeAndConstructionBusiness">
      <div itemprop="telephone" class="telephone">
        <a href="tel:+622585749">622 585 749</a>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="telephone" class="telephone">
        <a href="tel:+636740393">636 740 393</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/canalonesbastimar" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>


  .tel-fb {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    #tel {
      float: right;
      a {
        font-size: 29px;
        color: #009846;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }
    .fb-like {
      position: absolute;
      top: 250px;
      right: 3px;
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I finally added a wrapper for the the facebook like button:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.tel-fb {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

#tel {
  float: right;
}

#tel a {
  font-size: 29px;
  color: #009846;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
.jander {
  background: red;
}
.zero {
    margin-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.one {
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=151887748332358";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="zero">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/canalonesbastimar" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
<div class="one">jfklas</div>
</div>
    <div class="tel-fb">
      <div class="telicon my-icons-telicon" style="float: left"></div>
      <div id="tel" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HomeAndConstructionBusiness">
        <div itemprop="telephone" class="telephone">
          <a href="tel:+622585749">622 585 749</a>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="telephone" class="telephone">
          <a href="tel:+636740393">636 740 393</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Might be worth putting up the code your using, otherwise people won't know where it's going wrong. Coincidentally, I have always found positioning facebook's like widgets an unwieldy process.

Comment: you may need to set a z-index (ie7 quirk) on all relatively positioned parent elements. start with the facebook button and work your way up the html structure, checking every parent item for position:relative and applying a relevant z-index

Comment: @RudiKershaw You are completely right, I added my code.

Comment: @DaveHaigh Thanks, I have added the z-index to the parent, but it still doesn't work, anyway check the code in my question, maybe I place it wrong.. There aren't any more parents with relative property

Comment: The only thing I can think to try off the top of my head is to add a height and width to the .fb-like class css. I don't know how it's otherwise being given a size on facebook's side.

Comment: @RudiKershaw I have added but it keeps the facebook button in the same position as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the css for your `.fb-like` class is working because you have put it inside the brackets for the `.tel-fb` class css.

So this;

```
.tel-fb {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    #tel {
      float: right;
      a {
        font-size: 29px;
        color: #009846;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }
    .fb-like {
      position: absolute;
      top: 250px;
      right: 3px;
    }
  }  // <--- Notice bracket here putting .fb-like and #tel inside .tel-fb
```

Should be this;

```
.tel-fb {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;        
}

#tel {
  float: right;
}

#tel a {
  font-size: 29px;
  color: #009846;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fb-like {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  right: 3px;
}
```

It's worth noting that your `#tel` css is also inside the `tel-fb` class, which means that CSS probably won't work either.

Comment: @Thanks, I forgot to say that my code corresponds to a sass file, Then the sass file is converted to the code you mention as Should be this.

Comment: Ahh, okay. In which case I have no idea. The above code is working on my end.

Comment: Yes. Except I am testing it as an offline file, so I can't see the actual button. I am just using text and background-color to mark the div's position, and the div itself is moving fine.

Comment: I solved finally using a wrapper for the FB button, look at the question updated